# What Is Optimal Battery Usage & Lost for iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, battery

I am using my iPad  Pro about 2.5 years.

[image]

If %8 is lost from  iPad Battery in 2.5 years ( March 2016) is this a sign of a bad battery?

Comment: Hi Berk. I’m struggling to wrap my brain around “optimal” as in “how many miles per year is optimal for a vehicle”. Apple has a clear service standard where they will pay for a warranty or AppleCare swap so that’s a pretty binary standard. 80% published FCC at the point of evaluation. This seems like a yes/no question with one person to say yes - because X, Y and Z and another to say no with reasons A, B and C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple, you're not bad at all and very much in the healthy range.

- https://www.apple.com/batteries/service-and-recycling/

> iPad Owners
>
> > Your battery is designed to retain up to 80% of its original capacity at 1000 complete charge cycles. The one-year warranty includes service coverage for a defective battery. If it is out of warranty, [Apple offers a battery service](https://support.apple.com/ipad/repair/service) for $99, plus $6.95 shipping, subject to local tax.